# jQuery when $.each (which has $.ajax) finish, run function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have situation that on page there are multiple elements (from 2 to 20) and i would need to run $.each on them which have $.ajax call inside. 
That all happens async, and when all of these $.ajax calls finish, i would need t o continue with program...

What is the best way to accomplish this?

$.each is sync, but when i run $.ajax inside, the thing becomes async.
It seems to me that it is hard to use $.when and $.done since there are no fixed number of ajax calls.

?

Comment: Please include your code to help demonstrate the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't think it matters if you fire and forget an asynchronous `$.ajax()` methods, then continue iterating...

Comment: @NickBull - I need result from that $.ajax call to be displayed after all the $.ajax calls are finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your [`jqXhr Objects`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) in an `array` and call [`jQuery.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) using [`function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to use your array as parameters of `$.when`.

```
var deferreds = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    //ajax options
  });
  deferreds.push(jqxhr);
}

$.when.apply(this, deferreds).done(function(){
  //This will wait for all ajax requests to finish before running

  console.log(arguments); //arguments will contain the results of ajax requests
  //...
});
```